# href has no attribute 'get' when retrieving the first anchor tag from wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm getting `href has no attribute 'get'`. I'm trying to retrieve the first anchor tag in this web crawler. I used to extract the href directly like `p.a.['href']` and with `p.a.get('href')` it prints. But when I assign it to href1, it errors out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/asagarwala/IdeaProjects/Py1/new1.py", line 11, in <module>
print(soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find(class_='mw-parser- 
output').p.a.get('href'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger"

my_list = []
i = 1

while i < 26:
    html = requests.get(url1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    print(soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find(class_='mw-parser-output').p.a.get('href'))

    href1 = soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find(class_='mw-parser-output').p.a.get('href')
    url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + href1
    i += 1

    if href1 == 'wiki/Philosophy':
        print("philosophy reached. Bye")
        break

    my_list.append(url1)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Nothing was found by your request, nothing got printed. You must check if both `soup.find(id="mw-content-text")` and `soup.find(id="mw-content-text").find(class_='mw-parser- 
output')` exist before using them.

Comment: The request is 200 but the paragraph on the Emotion page is:
`<p class="mw-empty-elt"></p>` which has no `a` child. I assume you're doing a "21 steps to philosophy" thing. What kind of strategy are you using to get there?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are searching for the first `p` tag within the class. On your second iteration (in https://en.wikipedia.org/Anger), that is empty, and hence, you will get no results.

Try the following

```
In [176]: def wiki_travel(url):
     ...:     visited = []
     ...:     for i in range(26):
     ...:         html = requests.get(url)
     ...:         if not html.ok:
     ...:             print("'{0}' got response code {1}".format(url, html.status_code))
     ...:             break
     ...:
     ...:         soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
     ...:
     ...:         target = next((c.get('href') for p in soup.find(class_='mw-parser-output').findAll('p') for c in p.findAll('a') if c.get('href', '').startswith('/')), None)
     ...:         if not target:
     ...:             print('Target not found')
     ...:             break
     ...:
     ...:         print(target)
     ...:         url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + target
     ...:         if target == '/wiki/Philosophy':
     ...:             print('Philosophy reached. Bye')
     ...:             break
     ...:
     ...:         visited.append(url)
     ...:
     ...:     return visited
     ...:
```

Testing this

```
In [177]: wiki_travel('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger')
/wiki/Emotion
/wiki/Consciousness
/wiki/Quality_(philosophy)
/wiki/Philosophy
Philosophy reached. Bye
Out[177]:
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_(philosophy)']
```

The key is in the following line

```
target = next((c.get('href') for p in soup.find(class_='mw-parser-output').findAll('p') for c in p.findAll('a') if c.get('href', '').startswith('/')), None)
```

What's going on here? It's a generator which would be the similar to

```
target = []
# Search for all p tags within this class
for p in soup.find(class_='mw-parser-output').findAll('p'):
    # Find all a tags
    for c in p.findAll('a'):
        # Only add to target list iff the link starts with a '/'
        # I.e. no anchors ('#') which won't get us to a new page
        if c.get('href', '').startswith('/'):
            target.append(c.get('href'))
```

And either getting `target[0]` or `None` if no results are found.